# Validation Rule Not Functioning

Tags: validation-rule

Below is the validation rule that should trigger when: To close this move, the Art Handler Must enter Color Temp and Light Intensity for Fine Art items moving to NG2A or NG3A.

```
AND(
    $UserRole.Id = '00E8c000000FLzh',
    (RP_Category__c = 'Fine Art'),
    OR(
        CONTAINS(Location__c, 'NG2A'),
        CONTAINS(Location__c, 'NG3A')
    ),
    OR(
        ISBLANK(Color_Temp__c),
        ISBLANK(Light_Intensity__c)
    ),
    ISPICKVAL(Status__c, 'Complete')
)
```

When I log in as a profile with this Role.ID, I am not triggering the validation rule when I save the record. Any advice?

Comment: What is the field type of `Location__c`? Is it a text field, a relationship field, or something else?

Comment: Hi Derek, it is a lookup field to the Location Object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the Salesforce UI displays the name of the related record, the thing that's actually being stored in that field is the record's Id.

So your `Location__c` lookup relationship field will almost certainly never contain 'NG2A' or 'NG3A'. It's possible, but unlikely. Like, "find one particular grain of sand in the entire world" unlikely.

So instead of
`CONTAINS(Location__c, 'NG2A')`

You would want to use
`CONTAINS(Location__r.Name, 'NG2A')`

And you'd do the same for your 'NG3A' location as well.

`__c` becomes `__r` when you're using it to get data on a ***r***elated record, and you use dot-notation to access fields on that related record (just like if you were writing code or a query).

Comment: Thank you Sir! That worked. I appreciate your help!